# error en addSnapshotListener

Tags: java, android

Tengo una app que entra por usuario de firebase, pero a la hora de cerrar la app con un

```
 mAuth.signOut();
```

Me sale un error en este addSnapshotListener

```
mfirestoresedestotales = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    mfirestoresedestotales.collection("Sedes").whereEqualTo("idoposicion", gmidoposicion)
        .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value,@Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                if (!value.isEmpty()) {
                   ........ 
            }
        });
```

El error que sale es:

Process: com.oposiciones.tribunales, PID: 13882
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot.isEmpty()' on a null object reference
at com.oposiciones.tribunales.Sedes.ActivitySede$1.onEvent(ActivitySede.java:103)

No se porque me sale este error ya que esa pantalla ya esta cerrada. La linea 103 es la del if (!value.isEmpty()) {

Gracias

Comment: Hola. ¿Por qué no programas siguiendo los [ejemplos de la documentación](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/listen?hl=es-419#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collection)? Si analizas bien, primero debes verificar que no hay en error, y sólo entonces pasar a trabajar con la eventual respuesta, **después de esa verificación**. Es decir, algo así: `if (e != null) { Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", e); return; } //A partir de aquí trabajas con los datos if (!value.isEmpty()) { //... }` No puedes pasar a trabajar con los datos sin antes estar seguro de que no hubo error.

Answer (score 0):

En este caso debes de validar primeramente si estás teniendo un error, ya que el problema es que tu `QuerySnapshot` tiene valor `null` y tratas de llamar su método `.isEmpty()`, elimina la validación `if (!value.isEmpty()) {` , primero consulta si tienes un error:

```
mfirestoresedestotales = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    mfirestoresedestotales.collection("Sedes").whereEqualTo("idoposicion", gmidoposicion)
        .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value,@Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {

            if (e != null) { //* Valida si existe un error.
               System.err.println("Listen failed:" + e);
               return; //* Termina.
            }
            ...
            ...               
            ...

            }
        });
```